# Does using Spark SQL instead of Spark Dataframe operation impact code coverage?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Does using Spark SQL instead of Spark DF lower the quality of Code coverage in production code .
If so is there a way to improve Code Coverage even when using Spark SQLs and processing them using Scala Spark application

Comment: I don't see how it would differ. Better check by yourself on a concrete example though.

Comment: Also consider that code coverage is just one metric among many others and won't ensure your code correctness.

Comment: Thanks . So , is there any good reason to write complex transformations using data frame instead of SQL ? It seems it’s just way too many extra lines of code and it’s even harder to paremetrise the data frame operations

Comment: You can't do everything with plain SQL. Expressing a series of transformation over a dataset is likely to be clearer with code split over different functions than a gigantic SQL. There's also the `Dataset` Vs. `Dataframe` question depending on you're more familiar with SQL or Scala constructs to manipulate data.